# While loop exits too soon when executing name input

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I am trying to create a while loop for the user to enter their name. When their name is entered I am using a while loop for check if the name entered is real *Using String For This*. If the user does not enter a name, say they enter a value instead, then the while loop will prompt the user to enter the name again. Likewise, printing the name again at the bottom to confirm with the user, if the name was correctly inputed.

```C++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// g++ -std=c++14 -Wall main.cc -o main

int main() {

  string name;
  cout << "Please Enter Your Name: " << endl;


  while (name.compare ("Done") != 0) {
    getline(cin,name);
    if (name == " ") {
      cin.clear();
      cout << "\nPlease Enter Your Name: " << endl;
    } else break;
  }

  return 0;

  cout << "Is Your Name" << name << "?" << endl;
  // Ask Verification Here
}
```

Comment: *If the user does not enter a name, say they enter a value instead* It's not clear to me what you mean by that. I don't see any code that tests that. What do you mean by "value" and how is that different than a "name"?

Comment: I have not written that part yet, I was looking ti dix the top first

Comment: If the user simply hits the ENTER key, `name` will not contain a space character.    Your code will only prompt the user again if the user enters a space character followed by the enter key.   There is no test in your code to (say) check if the user has entered digits.

Comment: I think I fixed it @Peter, However stack doesn't me insert code.. how do I insert into the comment?

Comment: @ImranJuma don't put the code in a comment, [edit] your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for clearer code:

1. Move all the logic for checking whether a name is valid to its own function.

   ```
   bool isValidName(std::string const& name)
   {
      // Do all the validation tests and return true if name is valid.
      // Return false otherwise.
   }
   ```
2. Change the `while` loop to:

   ```
   while ( getline(cin,name) )
   {
      if ( name == "Done" )
      {
         break;
      }

      if ( isValidName(name) )
      {
         break;
      }

      // Ask for name again.
      cout << "\nPlease Enter Your Name: " << endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: I see what you mean, is there anyway I can do this all within the main function and edit my existing code?

Comment: @ImranJuma, of course there is but it is not as clean as doing that in a different function.

Answer (score 1):

[Break](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_break_statement.htm) is causing your loop to end. You either mean [continue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/continue), or don't need a break there at all.

Comment: Break means to end the loop right? Like it exits the loop?

Comment: @ImranJuma yes.